# How can I rotate the results of a query in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I would like to be able to rotate the results of a SQL Query so that instead of the results being returned in a series of rows the results are returned as a single row with multiple columns.
For example with the following table.

```
Create Table TestData 
(
things varchar(25)
)

Insert into TestData values ('Thing1') 
Insert into TestData values ('Thing2')
Insert into TestData values ('Thing3')
Insert into TestData values ('Thing4')
```

I would like a select statement like `Select things from TestData`

to return something like
Thing1 Thing2 Thing3 Thing4

rather than

1. Thing1
2. Thing2
3. Thing3
4. Thing4

Thanks in advance for the help.

Update:

After seeing the recommendation by Gratzy to use Pivot I found I can get the desired result by adding an identity column to the table like so.

```
Create Table TestData 
(
    id int identity,
    things varchar(25)
)
```

and then running the following.

```
SELECT *
FROM TestData
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Things)
    FOR [ID] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
)
AS Result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try PIVOT

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx