# TSQL - reorganize fields

Tags: t-sql

Suppose i have the following data in a table:

```
ID  Type    Preis
1   1   10
1   2   20
1   3   30
```

and now i want it reorganized like this:

```
ID  Preis_A Preis_B Preis_C
1   10  20  30
```

How can i do this in t-sql?

Comment: look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473272/how-to-pivot-in-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473272/how-to-pivot-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL Server are you using? Search here for Cross-Tab and/or Pivot.