# How to convert rows values into column in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to convert row into column.I have following result set.

```
UserID  VendorName  QuestionText AnswerText
1         KK         abc1         ans1
1         KK         abc2         ans2
1         KK         abc3         ans3
2         JJ         abc1         ans2
2         JJ         abc2         ans3
2         JJ         abc3         ans1
```

OUTPUT should be:

```
UserID VendorName   abc1    abc2   abc3
1             KK    ans1    ans2   ans3
2             JJ    ans2    ans3   ans1
```

Thanks.

Comment: This has been **asked** and **answered** at least a gazillion times here on SO - I would recommend a search for "SQL Server PIVOT" - you should have **tons** of answers!

Comment: Duplicate of [How to pivot in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473272/how-to-pivot-in-sql)

Comment: i tried using pivot but it require any aggregate function(count,sum) inside code block.but my column AnswerText has text value not any integer. so how to do it with PIVOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID, VendorName, [abc1], [abc2], [abc3]
FROM Questions
PIVOT (MAX(AnswerText)
    FOR QuestionText IN ([abc1], [abc2], [abc3])
) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT grsid,contactid, [1] rejectcode, [12] rejectcode, [89] rejectcode
FROM **rjct1**
PIVOT (MAX(rejectcode)
    FOR rejectcode IN ([1] , [12], [89])
) AS pvt
```